# How to get full referrer url in php

Tags: php, http-referer

I want to get full referrer url in PHP.
For instance, if I come to mywebsite from a google search, **`$_SERVER['REFERER']`** gives me only www.google.com, but I want smth like www.google.com/search?q=KEYWORD

Google Analytics provides that for many search engines. 
I need to get "**/search?q=KEYWORD**" query string.

Comment: are you sure its $_SERVER['REFERER'] and not this => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Ahhh.. [Google](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/464557-how-get-referrer-parameters)

Comment: /!\ Users using Google in HTTPS will not have any referrer.

Comment: Duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url

Comment: @JulienPalard google uses https on nearly most of there sites.

Comment: @joaobarbosa: possibly not duplicated!

Comment: Why not testing your site from another domain (not google.com), just see if it prints full URL of the referrer, I tested on my PC, I can see full URL of the referrer

Comment: @Class That's why I warn halilenver, if he want to extract data from referrer, he will have some but not all expected (I actually use referrers as a source and we yet have a usable bunch of users from non-https google search)

Comment: @JulienPalard is there anything that can be done to track google's query string when using https?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in your script and have a look at it's content;

```
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
?>
</pre>
```

This way you can find out which keys contain 'what'